# Alias for template base class function members

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm writing code that use a lot of templates and I often stumble across code that looks like this:

```
template<class T, class V>
struct Base {  Base(int a) {} };

template<class T, class V>
struct Derived : public Base<T,V>
 {
 using Base<T,V>::Base; // [1] ok it works
 using Base::Base; // [2] Does not work  
 };
```

Think when you write instead of T more meaningful names, the [1] statement becomes too long.. is there no way to use a statement like [2]? or is there something to simplify this in the forthcoming C++ standards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you *can* use the injected class name for such purposes. The problem here is that this injected class name is a member of a templated base class, ergo it's formally dependent, so it isn't found by the unqualified lookup that needs to pick up the first `Base` in `using Base::Base`.

But we can manipulate how lookup works here:

```
template<class T, class V>
struct Derived : public Base<T,V>
{
    using Derived::Base::Base;
};
```

`Derived` is the injected class name of `Derived<T,V>`. So that's found, and now we are doing qualified lookup for `Base`, so it being dependent is no longer an issue.

Comment: Mate this is awesome, it's exactly what I was looking for! where did you learn this stuff?

Comment: @svoltron Well, in that case please accept StoryTeller's answer by clicking the checkmark under the answer score ;)

Comment: @svoltron - Answering language lawyer questions on [SO] and stumbling into these  dark corners of the language in my own code. I never actually faced your specific issue, but the situation just clicked in my mind.

Comment: well, you should be proud of that then

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using just `Base::Base` is that the name `Base` (on the left-hand side) is supposed to be the injected-class-name of the parent `Base<T, V>`, but because that parent is dependent, it is not searched for names and thus the injected class name is not found.

You can get around this by using the injected class name in a dependent context, so that its lookup is postponed until instantiation. Like this:

```
template<class T, class V>
struct Derived : public Base<T,V>
 {
 using Derived::Base::Base;
 };
```

`Derived` is found normally (it's this instantiation's injected class name), and is known to be dependent, so the `Base` in the middle is known to be dependent and will only be looked up when instantiating `Derived`, at which time all bases are fully known and can be searched.

Comment: Thank you very much, same as for Storyteller,  this technique it's wonderful for template code!

Comment: @svoltron same comment.

Comment: Yep, not sure which one to accept in this case, they're both right and reply at the same time

Comment: I think I've to do something like that eheh

Comment: Angew I chose the Storyteller reply only because I saw it first. The answer is clear and wonderful as the Storyteller one, thank you again

Comment: @svoltron No problem at all, glad I helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a type alias with:

```
template<class T, class V>
struct Derived : public Base<T,V>
{
    using BaseClass = Base<T,V>;
    using BaseClass::Base;
};
```

The `using` keyword has three meaning in C++. It can introduce:

- a *using-directive*,
- a *using-declaration*,
- or a type alias.

A [*using-directive*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) has the form `using namespace please_not_std` and brings whatever is in the `please_not_std` namespace to the current scope (this is a simplification).

A [*using-declaration*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) has the form `using Class::name` and introduces a name that is defined elsewhere into the current scope.

A [type alias (C++11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) has the form `using new_type = existing_type` and defines ... a type alias.

Comment: yep I'm already doing this, but it's too much typing and error prone

Comment: Thank you for the further explanation